# use matplotlib plot function to plot 1000 points

Tags: python, matplotlib

guys
Normally I can use matplotlib to draw smoothly, but when I have more data points like 1000, the picture is becoming stacked, not smooth at all.

```
y = [0.1,0.5,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.43,0.55,0.76,0.90,0.66]
x = range(10)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

```
y = [0.1,0.5,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.43,0.55,0.76,0.90,0.66]*100
x = range(1000)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

So how to adjust the parameter to display 1000 points like a smooth line, and the one who know matplotlib deeply may leave a ETC address for the bonus,I d like to buy a cup of coffee for you, many thanks.

Comment: You are repeating the same sequence of 10 numbers 100 times, one after the other.  That is what is plotted. Its unclear what you would like to happen instead.

Answer (score 0):

Jody Klymak told you right, you have everything in order with the rendering.
I made a slider to scroll through your data. At the beginning they are all displayed.
But if you start scrolling through them, 100 items will be shown in a sliding window.
You will see that they are repeated and because of this, when visualizing all the elements, such a picture is obtained.
Of course, this is not quite the answer, but it shows why this is happening.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

Pl, Ax = plt.subplots()

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
y = [0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.43, 0.55, 0.76, 0.90, 0.66]*100
x = range(1000)
hist = len(x)

plt.plot(x, y)

axis_position = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
slider = Slider(axis_position,
                         'Pos', 0.1, hist)

def update(val):
    pos = slider.val
    Ax.axis([pos, pos + 100, 0, 1])
    Pl.canvas.draw_idle()

slider.on_changed(update)

def resetSlider(event):
    slider.reset()
    Ax.axis([0, hist, 0, 1])

resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color='gold',
                hovercolor='skyblue')

button.on_clicked(resetSlider)

plt.show()
```